# ID Request: What is this frog? Eastern Long Island, NY USA mixed hardwood forest

Tags: species-identification, amphibians

Apologies for the potato quality photos, but can anyone ID this frog?

My son found a few frogs living under a porch at my father's house, which is situated in a mixed hardwood forested area of eastern Long Island, NY. I say "living" because he sees them sitting just at the edge of the low porch every day for a while now.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to tell exactly from the photos, but given the location and time of year, it is either a juvenile green frog (*Rana clamitans*) or juvenile bull frog (*Rana catesbeiana*).

Comment: Would a juvenile bull frog be in an upland setting? I know there are bull frogs in the pond about 300m away, but I'd always thought of them staying in the pond.

Comment: Yes, they disburse quite far away from their natal ponds as juveniles, often into impermanent water sources, before settling in a permanent waterbody as adults.

Comment: Then I think bull frog is likely the answer